# Bucket policy Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Can't seem to figure out what im doing wrong. I keep getting this error code for my bucket policy.

> Unknown field Resources (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error
> Code: MalformedPolicy; Request ID: RZ83BT86XNF8WETM; S3 Extended
> Request ID:
> 44iFVUdgSJcvTItlZeIftDHPCKV4/iEqZXe7Zf45VL6y7HkC/3iz03Lp13OTIHjxhTEJGSvXXUs=;
> Proxy: null)

this is my code:

```
 BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: MyPolicy
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
            Effect: Allow  
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "s3:GetObject"
            Resources: !Join
              - ""
              - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                - !Ref MyWebsite
                - /*
      Bucket: !Ref MyWebsite
```

I tried going through my code to see what Im missing but cant figured it out

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a simple typographical mistake. Try using "Resource" instead of "Resources". There is no field called "Resources" in a bucket policy.

Please see the [this source for S3 Bucket Policy examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html) and [this User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html) for CloudFormation templates.